# Relation between charger output voltage and battery output voltage

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, charger

I'm searching into making a simple solar battery charger.
Right now I am kind of a newbie in this field so I am wondering what kind of voltage does the charger need to output in order to charge a 48 V battery or a 60 V one.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and can't be a personal tutorial service or a free design house. This is a one-line question that asks for mountains of effort in reply. There is plenty of existing text on this subject on the internet that you can look for. This Question will most likely be closed, though you can choose to delete it yourself before any downvotes reduce your Reputation. Take the Tour if you would like clarification on how the site operates. Again, welcome.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie,
Please make this an official answer and I'll accept it. It's what I was looking after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A charger will always need to output a slightly **higher** voltage than the battery to make current flow into the battery and charge it.

The **highest** voltage that a charger should output depends on the voltage that the battery will reach when fully charged. This voltage depends on the battery chemistry.

Learn more about batteries and how to charge them at [Battery University](https://batteryuniversity.com/)